# How to add conditionally data to Firebase Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm working on a project which is about to go live, using Google Firebase Firestore for data.

The users will be adding review through a form, but currently that form submit is:

```
firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection(props.collection)
    .add({
        item: entryName,
        value: parseInt(rate),
        description
    })
```

But honestly I wouldn't really love to let users adding items without my confirmation.

Any idea how it could be done? If not only Firebase Firestore it's fine as well, but I have no ideas.

Comment: It's really not clear what you're trying to do here.  What do you mean by "let users adding items without my confirmation"?  Writing to Firestore doesn't need any confirmation.  The code just runs, and it either succeeds or fails.

Comment: So it's like an e-commerce app, where users can add review to the items. But since anyone can add review, it would be good if I could check before that review actually getting published live.You know, for text correction, and to eliminate possible swear words.

Comment: is it worth to add a property to control this? Only when you change that in a proper UI, then it will be published.